# executing .bash_profile alias via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, shell

I would like to remotely execute a .bash_profile alias, but I cannot find the proper command.

I tried:
`ssh user@host "bash -ic myalias"`
but it doesn't work

I get:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Invalid argument  
bash: no job control in this shell  
bash: myalias: command not found
```

Comment: You get `myalias: command not found`. Have you made the alias!?

Comment: @Pazis, the alias exists in .bash_profile

Answer (score 3):

You could put the alias in a separate file. Then you would source it from your .bash_profile and the ssh command would look like:

```
ssh user@host bash -c '. .bash_aliases; shopt -s expand_aliases; myalias'
```

Comment: And the reason why the profile isn't read in the first place is that, as the man page says, "If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host **instead** of a login shell.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try putting the alias command in .bashrc instead of .bash_profile.

I tried this on one of my servers and the alias was recognized.

I believe that it is because ssh user@host  is a non-login shell. Usually .bash_profile is skipped for non-login shells.

Comment: There may be a line near the top of the .bash_profile script which stops execution for non-interactive shells.

Comment: This will not help. As the man page says, "If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell". It has nothing at all to do with the .bashrc since it never gets called since the login shell doesn't get called.